# Using sed to remove embedded newlines

Tags: sed, awk

What is a sed script that will remove the "\n" character but only if it is inside "" characters (delimited string), not the \n that is actually at the end of the (virtual) line?
For example, I want to turn this file

```
"lalala","lalalslalsa"
"lalalala","lkjasjdf
asdfasfd"
"lalala","dasdf"
```

(line 2 has an embedded \n ) into this one

```
"lalala","lalalslalsa"
"lalalala","lkjasjdf \\n asdfasfd"
"lalala","dasdf"
```

(Line 2 and 3 are now joined, and the real line feed was replaced with the character string \\n (or any other easy to spot character string, I'm not picky))

I don't just want to remove every other newline as a previous question asked, nor do I want to remove ALL newlines, just those that are inside quotes. I'm not wedded to sed, if awk would work, that's fine too.

The file being operated on is too large to fit in memory all at once.

Answer (score 2):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line but for anything else you should use awk., e.g:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    if (/"$/) {
        print prev $0
        prev = ""
    }
    else {
        prev = prev $0 " \\\\n "
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
"lalala","lalalslalsa"
"lalalala","lkjasjdf \\n asdfasfd"
"lalala","dasdf"
```

Below was my original answer but after seeing @NeronLeVelu's approach of just testing for a quote at the end of the line I realized I was doing this in a much too complicated way. You could just replace `gsub(/"/,"&") % 2` below with `/"$/` and it'd work the same but the above code is a simpler implementation of the same functionality and will now handle embedded escaped double quotes as long as they aren't at the end of a line.

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ $0 = saved $0; saved="" }
gsub(/"/,"&") % 2 { saved = $0 " \\\\n "; next }
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
"lalala","lalalslalsa"
"lalalala","lkjasjdf \\n asdfasfd"
"lalala","dasdf"
```

The above only stores 1 output line in memory at a time. It just keeps building up an output line from input lines while the number of double quotes in that output line is an odd number, then prints the output line when it eventually contains an even number of double quotes.

It will fail if you can have double quotes inside your quoted strings escaped as `\"`, not `""`, but you don't show that in your posted sample input so hopefully you don't have that situation. If you have that situation you need to write/use a real CSV parser.

Comment: good remark for the internal `\"`. One way could be to tranlsate it before action and back after so the code will still be the same between

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n ':load
/"$/ !{N
      b load
      }
:cycle
s/^\(\([^"]*"[^"]*"\)*\)\([^"]*"[^"]*\)\n/\1\3 \\\\n /
t cycle
p' YourFile
```

- load the lines in working buffer until a close line (ending with `"`) is found or end reach
- replace any \n that is after any couple of open/close `"` followed by a single `"` with any other caracter that `"` between  from the start of file by the escapped version of new line (in fact replace starting string + \n by starting string and escaped new line)
- if any substitution occur, retry another one (`:cycle` and `t cycle`)
- print the result
- continue until end of file

thanks to @Ed Morton for remark about escaped new line

Comment: @Larry Pieniazek has mentioned, the input file is large, so load whoel file in buffer is not good idea. Second, if break lines in three lines, then your codes still merge two lines only.

Comment: adapt for huge file (working only on "open" string at once). if at least 1 break line is found, it merge the line so if 1000 lines broken are in the same string, after merge, there is only 1 line for this. This is why I use the `t cycle`

Comment: oops, right. i forget to replace the escapped new line after my test. I modify the code

Comment: Simply testing for lines ending with a double quote was a much better idea than the way I was doing it (testing for an odd number of double quotes in the accumulated line). Nice! +1 or the approach (I still wouldn't do it in sed of course due to the relative complexity of the required code vs awk).

Comment: for the sed vs awk, in this case, this big s/// that make me go to awk (so much risk of code error on any modification compare to awk on this pattern) and perf are certainly also a poitn for awk, especially on huge file